# Calculation of the daily mean form 5 pm to 5 pm the next day

Tags: r

I'm am working with a data set which consists of meteorological data that has been measured every 30 mins. I was able to calculate the daily means (from 00:00 to 00:00), with the following function:

```
daily_func_sum<-function(ts.in,date.ts){
  ts.in.xts<-xts(ts.in,date.ts)
  t<-period.apply(ts.in.xts, endpoints(ts.in.xts,"days"), sum)
  new.df<-data.frame(date=index(t), par_name=coredata(t))
  return(new.df)}
```

My data is looking like this:

```
           DateTime   Globalstrahlung Regen..30m Luft.Temperatur rel..Feuchte Luftdruck Windvelocity
1  2019-05-01 00:00:00       0          0            10.1         88.4       993          0.6
2  2019-05-01 00:30:00       0          0            10.4         81.5       993          0.5
3  2019-05-01 01:00:00       0          0             9.8         80.8       992          0.8
4  2019-05-01 01:30:00       0          0             9.2         82.2       993          0.4
5  2019-05-01 02:00:00       0          0             9.1         83.2       993          0.6
6  2019-05-01 02:30:00       0          0             6.8         97.4       993            0
7  2019-05-01 03:00:00       0          0             5.8         99.9       993            0
8  2019-05-01 03:30:00       0          0             6.6         96.9       992          0.4
9  2019-05-01 04:00:00       0          0             5.8         99.3       992          0.7
10 2019-05-01 04:30:00       3          0             5.1          100       993          0.5
```

I would like to calculate the daily means based on the time period from 5 pm on the first to 5 pm on the second day. So for example from 2019.05.01 05:00 to 2019.05.02 5:00. So far i have not found a way to incorporate my desired time span into my function. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit:
This is the data that Georgery asked for.

```
> dput(WS_full_corr[1:50,])
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1556668800, 1556670600, 
1556672400, 1556674200, 1556676000, 1556677800, 1556679600, 1556681400, 
1556683200, 1556685000, 1556686800, 1556688600, 1556690400, 1556692200, 
1556694000, 1556695800, 1556697600, 1556699400, 1556701200, 1556703000, 
1556704800, 1556706600, 1556708400, 1556710200, 1556712000, 1556713800, 
1556715600, 1556717400, 1556719200, 1556721000, 1556722800, 1556724600, 
1556726400, 1556728200, 1556730000, 1556731800, 1556733600, 1556735400, 
1556737200, 1556739000, 1556740800, 1556742600, 1556744400, 1556746200, 
1556748000, 1556749800, 1556751600, 1556753400, 1556755200, 1556757000
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Timestamp = c(43586, 
43586.02083, 43586.04167, 43586.0625, 43586.08333, 43586.10417, 
43586.125, 43586.14583, 43586.16667, 43586.1875, 43586.20833, 
43586.22917, 43586.25, 43586.27083, 43586.29167, 43586.3125, 
43586.33333, 43586.35417, 43586.375, 43586.39583, 43586.41667, 
43586.4375, 43586.45833, 43586.47917, 43586.5, 43586.52083, 43586.54167, 
43586.5625, 43586.58333, 43586.60417, 43586.625, 43586.64583, 
43586.66667, 43586.6875, 43586.70833, 43586.72917, 43586.75, 
43586.77083, 43586.79167, 43586.8125, 43586.83333, 43586.85417, 
43586.875, 43586.89583, 43586.91667, 43586.9375, 43586.95833, 
43586.97917, 43587, 43587.02083), Time = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("", "00:00:00", 
"00:30:00", "01:00:00", "01:30:00", "02:00:00", "02:30:00", "03:00:00", 
"03:30:00", "04:00:00", "04:30:00", "05:00:00", "05:30:00", "06:00:00", 
"06:30:00", "07:00:00", "07:30:00", "08:00:00", "08:30:00", "09:00:00", 
"09:30:00", "10:00:00", "10:30:00", "11:00:00", "11:30:00", "12:00:00", 
"12:30:00", "13:00:00", "13:30:00", "14:00:00", "14:30:00", "15:00:00", 
"15:30:00", "16:00:00", "16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", 
"18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00", "20:00:00", "20:30:00", "21:00:00", 
"21:30:00", "22:00:00", "22:30:00", "23:00:00", "23:30:00"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = c("2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", 
    "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", 
    "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", 
    "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", 
    "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", 
    "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", 
    "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", 
    "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", 
    "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", 
    "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-05-02", 
    "2019-05-02"), Power = c("11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
    "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
    "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
    "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
    "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
    "11", "11", "11", "11"), Cold.junction = c("10", "9.5", "8.9", 
    "8.4", "8", "7.6", "6.8", "5.9", "5.5", "5.2", "4.8", "4.6", 
    "4.9", "6.1", "8.8", "12.2", "14.6", "16", "16.8", "17.7", 
    "18.7", "19.8", "20.9", "21.9", "22.8", "23.7", "24.6", "25.3", 
    "25.8", "26.7", "25.4", "23.1", "22.6", "22.3", "22", "21.4", 
    "20.2", "18.6", "17.1", "16", "15.2", "14.2", "13.5", "13.3", 
    "13.2", "12.9", "12.6", "12.4", "11.9", "11.4"), Globalstrahlung = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "21", "51", 
    "94", "147", "341", "419", "493", "584", "664", "726", "771", 
    "827", "874", "898", "918", "907", "904", "884", "868", "574", 
    "668", "289", "437", "386", "311", "169", "50", "27", "6", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Regen..30m = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0"), Luft.Temperatur = c("10.1", "10.4", "9.8", "9.2", "9.1", 
    "6.8", "5.8", "6.6", "5.8", "5.1", "4.6", "5", "6.3", "10.1", 
    "11.5", "12.4", "12.9", "13.4", "14.3", "14.7", "15.6", "16", 
    "16.9", "17.6", "17.6", "18.4", "18.6", "18.9", "19.4", "20.4", 
    "18.5", "19.2", "18.6", "18", "17.9", "17.4", "16.8", "15.6", 
    "14.6", "14.8", "13.7", "13.2", "13.5", "13.4", "12.8", "12.6", 
    "12.5", "12", "11.5", "11.2"), rel..Feuchte = c("88.4", "81.5", 
    "80.8", "82.2", "83.2", "97.4", "99.9", "96.9", "99.3", "100", 
    "100", "100", "100", "81.2", "73.6", "71.1", "66.2", "58.9", 
    "57.7", "51.8", "53.7", "52.2", "48.4", "46", "39", "40.3", 
    "37.6", "34.1", "36.1", "32.3", "43.7", "51.9", "53.8", "54.7", 
    "52", "55.6", "57.2", "64.5", "71.6", "67.2", "74.1", "79.5", 
    "75.3", "75.2", "80.8", "80.7", "79.7", "80.8", "82.8", "87"
    ), Luftdruck = c("993", "993", "992", "993", "993", "993", 
    "993", "992", "992", "993", "993", "993", "993", "993", "993", 
    "993", "993", "993", "993", "993", "993", "993", "993", "993", 
    "993", "993", "992", "992", "992", "992", "992", "991", "991", 
    "992", "992", "991", "992", "992", "992", "992", "992", "992", 
    "992", "993", "992", "992", "992", "992", "992", "992"), 
    Windvelocity = c("0.6", "0.5", "0.8", "0.4", "0.6", "0", 
    "0", "0.4", "0.7", "0.5", "0.7", "0.5", "0.4", "1", "1.7", 
    "2", "2.2", "3.2", "3.1", "2.9", "2.3", "2.8", "2.8", "2.6", 
    "2.6", "2.5", "2.3", "3.1", "2.6", "2.7", "2.9", "3.4", "3.7", 
    "3.6", "3.3", "2.9", "2.7", "2.1", "1.3", "2.1", "0.4", "0.5", 
    "1.3", "0.8", "0", "0.8", "1.3", "0.8", "0", "0"), Windrichtung = c("261.9", 
    "304.3", "279.1", "0", "292.5", "0", "0", "247.8", "82.9", 
    "73.8", "86.7", "79.5", "67.1", "283.1", "273.8", "281.6", 
    "280.6", "280.6", "276", "261.2", "269.5", "258.2", "271.5", 
    "255.5", "262.2", "241.2", "260.8", "253.7", "250.4", "261.1", 
    "268.6", "253.8", "265.3", "252", "262.7", "254", "262.7", 
    "269.5", "239.6", "276.8", "272", "244", "263.1", "247.8", 
    "0", "238.9", "238", "241.8", "0", "0"), Globalstrahlung.Avg = c("0.1", 
    "0.1", "0.1", "0", "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", "0", "0", "0.8", 
    "10.1", "37.7", "74.7", "112.2", "277.5", "389.5", "453.7", 
    "540.5", "625.7", "695.9", "748.2", "801.1", "855.3", "889.5", 
    "910.7", "912.5", "903.1", "885.2", "855.7", "879.1", "339.1", 
    "317.2", "408.6", "395", "333.7", "239.9", "118.3", "37.8", 
    "14.6", "1.8", "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", 
    "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", "0.1"), Globalstrahlung.Max = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "21", "51", 
    "94", "160", "341", "419", "493", "584", "664", "726", "771", 
    "830", "875", "898", "919", "920", "916", "899", "897", "962", 
    "889", "708", "577", "458", "405", "308", "190", "52", "26", 
    "5", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Globalstrahlung.Min = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "23", "53", 
    "87", "132", "348", "417", "497", "585", "665", "726", "770", 
    "827", "875", "897", "905", "890", "875", "753", "294", "172", 
    "111", "216", "258", "278", "147", "49", "27", "6", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Windvelocity.Avg = c("0.2", 
    "0.8", "0.4", "0.5", "0.7", "0.3", "0.3", "0", "0.3", "0.7", 
    "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.3", "1.5", "2", "1.9", "2.9", "3.2", 
    "3", "2.7", "2.6", "2.7", "2.7", "2.7", "2.6", "2.6", "2.6", 
    "2.9", "2.9", "2.9", "2.9", "3.7", "4", "3.2", "3", "2.9", 
    "2.5", "1.6", "1.9", "1.1", "0.6", "1", "1.3", "0.6", "0.4", 
    "1", "0.9", "0.4", "0"), Windvelocity.Max = c("0.6", "1.2", 
    "0.8", "0.8", "0.8", "0.6", "0.6", "0.4", "0.7", "0.8", "0.7", 
    "0.7", "0.6", "1", "1.8", "2.2", "2.4", "3.5", "3.9", "3.3", 
    "3.1", "2.9", "2.9", "2.9", "2.8", "2.9", "3.2", "3.1", "3.3", 
    "3.3", "4", "3.4", "4.2", "4.3", "3.5", "3.4", "3.2", "2.8", 
    "2.1", "2.2", "1.9", "0.8", "1.3", "1.7", "1", "0.8", "1.3", 
    "1.3", "0.8", "0.3"), Windvelocity.Min = c("0", "0.5", "0", 
    "0.3", "0.4", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.5", "0.3", "0.4", "0.4", 
    "0", "0.9", "1.7", "1.6", "2.4", "2.5", "2.8", "2.3", "2.3", 
    "2.4", "2.4", "2.5", "2.4", "2.1", "2.2", "2.6", "2.6", "2.4", 
    "2.7", "3.4", "3.5", "3", "2.5", "2.4", "2.1", "1.2", "1.2", 
    "0.4", "0.4", "0.6", "0.8", "0", "0", "0.7", "0.7", "0", 
    "0")), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Previously i deleted the columns Date, Time, Power and Cold.junction since they are irrelevant for my analysis.

Comment: Can you post some data using `dput(your_dataframe[1:50,])`? (Just post the output of that here.)

Comment: Thanks for the update. For some reason your dput data has the numeric columns actually in character, but it should work generally. If you think below is the answer, then please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't exactly know your dataset, but maybe this helps:

```
library(tidyverse) # several packages that help
library(lubridate) # package for dealing with dates and times



# we take the dataframe
df %>%
    # ...create an additional column that is the actual time minus 5 hours and 
    # floor it to the "day" - i.e. same value if between 5:00 and 4:59 next day.
    mutate(adjusted_datetime = floor_date(DateTime - hours(5), unit = "day")) %>%
    # and now for each of those days...
    group_by(adjusted_datetime) %>%
    # we calculate the mean
    summarise(mean_globalstrahlung = mean(Globalstrahlung, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I've been testing your solution a bit, and i think it is working. I just have one little problem. It might be that i'm stupid, but i cant save the result of your code to a new data frame.

Comment: Really? You do `df_new <- df %>% mutate(......` and it doesn't work?

Comment: Ok i really was stupid :) Thank you a lot for your help!